How to get the absolute mouse position without Activity?
I am new in Android development and I am trying to extend function for scrcpy-server.
The scrcpy-server is an executable file that can be directly send to device via adb and be executed  by adb shell.
It does not have neither the Activity nor the View, and the related method like GenericMotionEvent seems not work.
After searching and asking LLMs, i got two ways and they do not work:

getevent: with getevent command, i can only get the relative movement of cursor

i also tried to calculate the absolute position by relative movement integral, but there is always some error so i think this approach might not be feasible.


startActivityAsUser: i noticed that the scrcpy.wrappers.ActivityManager has a method startActivity, which calls the startActivityAsUser method. I tried to use it to create an activity from an activity class or a package name, but it seems i has no permission to do so.

Would there be any way to implement that? Thank you so much!
